# HTML input element range detect when a drag is over

Tags: javascript, html, input

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1" />
```

Using Javascript how can I detect when the user has finished dragging a input:range element?

I've tried to use onblur, onmouseout and ondragend events.

Looking for a native javascript solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `onchange` or `onmouseup`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKp4M/2/)

Comment: Thank you, I should have went through them all!

Comment: Note: `onchange` is fired continuosly on chrome and safari, not just once user has finished dragging.

Comment: @Fabio, what would be the proper event for notification when user stop dragging in the end?

Comment: @RudolfSchmidt My comment was from 2014, the behavior on Chrome seems to have since changed. Not sure about Safari, if nothing changed, there might be no event like the one you need. You might want to still listen for the `onchange` event, but — depending on your requirements — filter or limit the throughput.